Asserting that a function that is mocked is called_once but running into ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
I am trying to unit test that a function is called within another function.
def run_this_function(something):
    'FOLD', {}

def go_to_the_right_street(action):
    if street_we_are_on == 'pre_flop_play':
        action, extra_information = run_this_function(something)

And my unit test looks like:
def test_go_to_the_right_street(street_we_are_on):


with patch('pb.app.run_this_function') as mocked_function:
    actual = go_to_the_right_street('some_value')
    # mocked_function.return_value = 'FOLD', {}  tried this too but I get the same error
    mocked_function.assert_called_once()

When I run the above, I get:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)


Your test double needs to have the same interface as the thing it's replacing, before it gets called.

What did you mean by test double?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double, https://blogs.vmware.com/tanzu/choosing-the-right-test-double/

I have created the following structure on my filesystem:
project
  |-pb
  |  |-app.py
  |-test_app.py

File app.py:
def run_this_function(something):
    return 'FOLD', {}

def go_to_the_right_street(street_we_are_on):
    if street_we_are_on == 'pre_flop_play':
        action, extra_information = run_this_function('something') <--- added the string definition for 'something' instead something as variable

In this file is present only a modification (see the comment in it).
File test_app.py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from pb.app import go_to_the_right_street

# I have defined this function to substitute your function run_this_function()
def run_this_function_patch(something):
    return 'FOLD', {}

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_go_to_the_right_street(self):
        with patch('pb.app.run_this_function') as mocked_function:
            mocked_function.side_effect = [run_this_function_patch('something')]  # <--- added this side_effect to return 'FOLD', {}
            actual = go_to_the_right_street('pre_flop_play')
            # mocked_function.return_value = 'FOLD', {}  tried this too but I get the same error
            mocked_function.assert_called_once()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

The 2 most important changes:

I have added the function run_this_function_patch() which is used to define the side_effect; note the presence of the parenthesis [] and ()
The instruction: mocked_function.side_effect = [run_this_function_patch('something')]  is defined before the calling of the function go_to_the_right_street()

With this code the output of the execution is the following:
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK


I had one question actually, how come we need mocked_function.side_effect = [run_this_function_patch('something')]  rather than something like mocked_function.side_effect = [FOLD, {}]  .
I don't quite understand the subtlety as to why we need the function call to run_this_function_patch

When you use side_effect you ask to execute a new function instead your function run_this_function. Inside the squared parenthesis [...] you have to put the functions that you need to execute in the order that you need. You can't insert into the parenthesis the return value.

@killerbee88 For example a mock objecy is a test double. In other words a test double is an object which substitute the real object and that has a behavior that can be set according to our needs.
